# how to graph centroids with KMeans

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working with a data set and trying to learn how to use cluster analysis and KMeans. I started out with a scatter plot graphing 2 attributes, and when I add a third attribute, and try and graph a another centroid I get an error. The code I am running is the following:

```
import numpy as np ##Import necassary packages
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import *
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 


url2="http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data" #Reading in Data from a freely and easily available source on the internet
Adult = pd.read_csv(url2, header=None, skipinitialspace=True) #Decoding data by removing extra spaces in cplumns with skipinitialspace=True
##Assigning reasonable column names to the dataframe
Adult.columns = ["age","workclass","fnlwgt","education","educationnum","maritalstatus","occupation",  
                 "relationship","race","sex","capitalgain","capitalloss","hoursperweek","nativecountry",
                 "less50kmoreeq50kn"]
Adult.loc[:, "White"] = (Adult.loc[:, "race"] == "White").astype(int)

X = pd.DataFrame()
X.loc[:,0] = Adult.loc[:,'age']
X.loc[:,1] = Adult.loc[:,'hoursperweek']
X.loc[:,2] = Adult.loc[:, "White"]

kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = 3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print(centroids)
print(labels)

colors = ["green","red","blue"]

plt.scatter(X.iloc[:,0], X.iloc[:,1], X.iloc[:,2], c=np.array(colors)[labels], alpha=.1)

plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1],  marker = "x", s=150, 
    linewidths = 5, zorder = 10, c=['green', 'red','blue'])
plt.show()
```

Running the code works however it does not seem correct as there are only 2 centroids being 'called' but 3 centroids are still plotted. when I change the centroid scatter plot to:

```
plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], centroids[:, 2] marker = "x", s=150, 
        linewidths = 5, zorder = 10, c=['green', 'red','blue'])
```

I get a `TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 's'`. Is the original incorrect code and will it cause problems in future projects? if so how should I change the code to where I do not receive an error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is **if you pass argument values without keys,scatter function expect 3rd argument to be s**.In your case third argument is centroid and again you passing `s` as a keyword argument.so it got multiple values to `s`.what you need is something like this.

1) Assign the columns of centroids: centroids_x, centroids_y

```
centroids_x = centroids[:,0]
centroids_y = centroids[:,1]
```

2) Make a scatter plot of centroids_x and centroids_y

```
plt.scatter(centroids_x,centroids_y,marker = "x", s=150,linewidths = 5, zorder = 10, c=['green', 'red','blue'])
```

Comment: What is the argument s that scatter is expecting? I tried to change my code the way you showed above, but I still get the error when trying to assign 3 centroids. I assigned  centroids_x1 = centroids[:,0],centroids_x2 = centroids[:,1], and centroids_x2 = centroids[:,2], and tried repotting the scatter plot and received another error.

Comment: you don't need `centroids[:,2]`. you have all points inside the centroids_x and centroids_y arrays.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought it was necessary to have a centroids[;,2] for another centroid, I wasn't sure if only having the centroids[:,0] and centroids[:,1] was enough

Comment: if this is solve your issue please mark as answer.. happy coding

Comment: I marked it, sorry sometimes forget that step. Thanks again!